# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '""' when using BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use BehaviorSubject and send Data from a service to a component but get the error in the component :
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '""'.

**Service**

```
assembleDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
assembleData$ = this.assembleDataSubject.asObservable();

composeData(data: string) {
this.assembleDataSubject.next(data);
}
```

**Component**

```
data = '';
receiveData(serviceData) {

 this.service.assembleData$.subscribe(
    serviceData => (this.data = serviceData), // the error occurs at this.data 
    error => console.log(error)
  );

  return this.data;
}
```

I've read a lot of other posts to that kind of failure but I am not able to map the answers to my problem. For me it seems to be different than the other questions because string should be the same as ' ' and because I use kind of standard code. It is just the way BehaviorSubjects are used. If I change anything there I get other failure messages.

Comment: i would try to change the name of the parameter `serviceData` as you use the same wording for the result of the subscription.

Comment: try to set an explicit type for your data field: `data: string = ''`

Comment: I just gave them some "mock names" thats not the original code. In the original code those two got different names.

Comment: @SNnaKR: You're trying to return the async variable `this.data` synchronously. It will either return undefined or it's old value. Instead you need to subscribe where the response from the `assembleData$` observable is required.

Comment: @Michael D you'r right I just run straight into that it always returns the initial value. What do you mean with "where the response from the observable is required" ? From my perspective I needed it right there in that function.

Comment: @SNnaKR: Simply put, all the statements that are dependent on the data from the observable **should** be inside the subscription. But you're returning the variable outside the subscription. It seems you're trying to do something like `someVar = receiveData(serviceData)` somewhere else in the code. That won't be possible. So you need to subscribe where you're attempting this assignment which is obviously outside the subscription.